# Euro character not showing in bold Gotham font

Tags: css, fonts

So I'm using the font Gotham Bold for some text on my page. However, the euro character keeps showing up in the "book" style instead of "bold":

[image: euro character]

As I converted the font straight from my fonts on my computer, I thought maybe the € character was simple missing, but when I look in my Font Book it is there:

[image: gotham bold]

So then I thought, maybe this happens because I didn't converted all the characters while using a font web generator, but then I tried another one and chose to convert all characters and still no luck...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try ascii euro sign? &#8364; or &euro;

Comment: I tried &euro; and &#8364 is that what you mean?

Comment: How did you convert the font files? Some converters include by default only a small subset of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting Gotham or any other licensed font for that matter is a breach of the font licensing.

You can purchase Gotham Bold and any other weights you may need from 
http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/webfonts/gotham-bold/

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Hello. I am currently doing my internship in a company which actually bought the font. I received the files as .tff extensions from a co-worker. If this appears to be the problem, I'll ask for the proper web font files.

Comment: You will need to check the license, you need different licenses for desktop and web fonts. If your company has purchased the web font license you will be able to either download and host the fonts or more likely there will be some javascript to put in the top of the page that will allow you to use a remote font.